# how to send data to 15 meters with KY-005

Tags: arduino-uno, infrared

I am using the LED [KY-005](https://arduinomodules.info/ky-005-infrared-transmitter-sensor-module/) as emitter and the [KY-022](https://arduinomodules.info/ky-022-infrared-receiver-module/) as a receiver, according to their specifications they reach 18 meters.
I have performed the tests and it supports more than ten meters, however after the 6 meters the data is not received correctly. For example, I send 0xa90 but any other value except the desired one arrives at the receiver.
Here I leave the connection diagram:
[image]

This is the code that I use to send data:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
IRsend irsend;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) { 
     irsend.sendSony(0xa90, 12); // Sony TV power code
     delay(40);
   }
}
```

Comment: the link to KY-022 is invalid

Comment: you only posted 1/2 the information

Comment: The link it's ok now.

Comment: I'm sure they've tested this in special conditions to better the results, with minimal external influences. Unless you know the testing procedure, there's no way of reproducing it.

Comment: Datasheet (http://www.datasheet4u.com/datasheet/T/L/1/TL1838-OpenImpulse.pdf.html) claims minimal 10m, typical 15m receiving distance with the "L5IR = 300MA" test signal. Now if we only knew what that was..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the emitter breakout board there is only a LED, nothing more. Comments in the linked page of the supplier states, that the 5V pin of it is not connected to anything. This means you are driving the LED directly from the Arduinos pin, which cannot provide more than 40mA. The supplier states a forward current from 30 to 60mA. You can use a small MOSFET in combination with a resistor, that limits the current to maybe 55mA, to drive the LED indirectly.

With this you won't fry the pins hardware and can provide more current, which means the LED can shine brighter. If you can find out, what LED is actually used for this board, you can refer directly to its datasheet. I couldn't find a part number at the site.